# How to use an absolute directory path for static files with OWIN self-hosting ASP app?

Tags: asp.net, owin, static-files

I have an OWIN self-hosting app with the option, and I have been passing requests to static files via the `appBuilder.UseStaticFiles("/Public/...")` option.

But this takes the 'build' directory as root. How do I specify a directory as an absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: https://richardniemand.wordpress.com/2015/06/18/hosting-web-api-and-static-content-with-owin/

Then slightly modified from the blog post, the code I needed:

```
PhysicalFileSystem physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"C:/www/websiteName");
FileServerOptions options = new FileServerOptions
{
    RequestPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Public"),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
    EnableDefaultFiles = true,
    FileSystem = physicalFileSystem
};
options.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new[]
{
    "index.html"
};
appBuilder.UseFileServer(options);
```

Then in my AJAX requests I can use the URI `/Public/.../something.js`

Answer (score 1):

OP's answer made my absolute folder path available for directory browsing, but files were still throwing 404. These lines in web.config made everything work as expected

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Configuration above made also my local static files inaccessible.
So I had to invoke configuration method two times.

```
app.UseFileServer(options);
app.UseFileServer();
```